# How to create a new Thread object on each iteration of the while loop? 'RuntimeError: threads can only be started once'

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I am new to the THREADING module, so i have been trying different simple approaches to the problem, but nothing works; keep getting: 'RuntimeError: threads can only be started once' error

```
from threading import Thread


def task():
   print('starting task..')
   time.sleep(1)
   print('done')

thread = Thread(target=task)

while True:
   print('Fresh start')

   thread.start()
   thread.join()

   print('Lets create a new thread for the next iteration')
```

.

i've tried randomizing an argument of the thread using RANDOM module:

```
def random_number():
   min_val = 1
   max_val = 1000000
   number = random.randint(min_val, max_val)
   return number

def thread_generator():
   thread1 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(10,random_number(),))
   thread1.start()
```

doesn't work

Also tried getting threads from a list and checking if they are running VIA is_alive:

```
threads = []
def thread_generator():
   for n in range(1, 101):
      thread = Thread(target=task, args=(10, n,))
      threads.append(thread)

def new_thread():
   for thread in threads:
      if not thread.is_alive():
        thread.start()
```

doesn't work

Comment: Do you remember what you normally do to do something on every iteration of a while loop?

Comment: @user2357112 can you tell me?

Comment: A while loop runs the loop body on every iteration. So if you want something to happen on every iteration, where do you put it?

Comment: Thread is in the loop, (as you can see in the code) the problem is: you cant use the same thread twice; you get: 'RuntimeError: threads can only be started once' error

Comment: You put the code to *start* the thread in the loop. But you want to *create* a thread on every iteration. Where is the code that *creates* the thread?

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Thank you!

Comment: Please do not fix the code in your question after you get an answer. We want the questions and answers to continue to make sense for people who find them when they search for answers to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to reuse the same thread since you are declaring it once (outside the loop).

You need to create a new thread by calling the constructor inside the loop as well:

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def task():
   print('starting task..')
   time.sleep(1)
   print('done')


while True:
   print('Fresh start')

   thread = Thread(target=task)
   thread.start()
   thread.join()

   print('Lets create a new thread for the next iteration')
```

Comment: Address the OP’s second and third code blocks too.